# utf8 error in GAE Datastore Viewer (Go runtime)

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, go

I am writing a webapp with the Go runtime in GAE.

I am saving a struct which contains a string, which is the result of hashing the bytes of another string with MD5, and then encoding the hash sum bytes into a string with hex.

Here is some code:

```
foo := "some string"
hashedFoo := md5.New()
hashedFoo.Write([]byte(foo))
encodedFoo := hex.EncodeToString(hashedFoo.Sum()) // this is what I'm assigning to my struct, and then saving into the Datastore
```

This works fine, no complaints when saving or retrieving the stored entities (through code), however, when loading the Datastore Viewer, I get an error that says something like "`Error fetching entities: Property Foo is corrupt in the datastore`", and then there is a traceback with a bunch of references to internal GAE files and then this: "`UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x85 in position 1: unexpected code byte`". This does not happen in the local development Datastore Viewer, only in the live production one.

So my questions are: what encoding does `hex.EncodeToString()` use? Is there a way to specify utf-8 output? Is this a GAE bug, or is it indeed a bad encoding error?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't know much about the the Go datastore API, but in Python, you must distinguish between byte strings and text strings by using the appropriate property in your model (ByteProperty or TextProperty; StringProperty is like TextProperty but indexed).  I think you need to somehow cast the result of EncodeToString to []byte.  Or maybe EncodeToString is not the function you need?

Comment: Right, thanks, there is indeed a distinction between `[]byte` and `string` in the Go API, I really didn't want to do this since it seems a bit hacky but I'll try it anyway. I am almost certain that there is a `hex` method to encode directly to `[]byte` and this way I could avoid casting, of which I'm not a fan in these cases.

Comment: @GuidovanRossum this was indeed the problem, I had a rogue line that was casting `hashedFoo.Sum()` directly into a string, instead of encoding through `hex`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was a rogue line that was casting `hashedFoo.Sum()` directly into a string and assigning that to `encodedFoo`. This produced some strings with characters not recognizable by utf-8.

`hex.EncodeToString()` works fine.

I guess this is a lesson for myself to keep my code clean and tidy :)